# How to set JSON return time in python flask

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

In my flask application, the front-end and back-end are separated. How can I return a JSON to front-end everyday at a specific time that I set.

For example

```
@api.route('/sda')
def Daily():
    # Get all entries (all students from all courses) that match today's date in MMDDYYYY format
    entries = Entry.query.filter_by(timestamp.strftime('%M%D%Y')=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%M%D%Y')).all()
    # Count how many students attend school today (Since in the entries array, there are duplicate student with same ID, and I only want to count it once per student)
    # When the loop ends, it will return a jsonify with today's date and total number of students attend school today
```

Expected data in JSON file:

```
{
  "dsa": [
    {
      "date": "12252014", 
      "present": 470,
      "absent": 30
    }, 
    {
      "date": "12262014", 
      "present": 490,
      "absent": 10
    }, 
    {
      "date": "12272014", 
      "present": 400,
      "absent": 100
    }
}
```

Since I realize that whenever front-end access the route `/sda` the function will return jsonify every time, and duplicate the value in JSON file with same `date`.

Comment: What are you asking for actually?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, the best course of action would be to do something like this.

Create a dictionary, and add an item (dsa) with an empty list as the value

```
myDict = {'dsa':[]}
```

Then in this list, add subsequent dictionaries

```
myDict['dsa'].append({"date":myDate, "present":present,"absent":absent})
```

Then just return  `json.dumps(myDict)`